# How to handle pop up which came after i clicked on child window of some parent window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can Anyone help now i have updated the code

I am trying to switch to third child window by the below code but I am getting the error as "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with".
Not sure what went wrong

```
Set<String> set= driver.getWindowHandles();
//As set in not indexable collection; create iterator to access items(Strings) in set
            Iterator<String> it=set.iterator();
    //Use next() method of iterator to access elements one by one from set
            String parentwin=it.next();
            String childwin=it.next();
//Pass webdriver control to child window and click on Actions drop down and select "Sync Google Sheet" option.
            driver.switchTo().window(childwin);
            /*WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='products_ingested']/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/button")));*/
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='products_ingested']/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/button")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='products_ingested']/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a")).click();

            //New window will open; now pass control to this new window and perform operation on it.

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Set<String> set1= driver.getWindowHandles();
            Iterator<String> it1=set1.iterator();
            String parentwin1=it1.next();
            String childwin1=it1.next();
            String childwin2=it1.next();
            System.out.println(childwin1);
            System.out.println(childwin2);
            System.out.println(parentwin1);
            //pass control to this third window
            driver.switchTo().window(childwin2);
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            //Writing code to perform operations on this third window 
            Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("spreadsheet_select")));
            sel.selectByVisibleText("Test Sheet {AKASH.SRIVASTAVA}");
```

Comment: Did you try anything to handle that popup?

Comment: I tried to write the code for window handling but its not working out this pop up has arisen after i have clicked on the child window of some parent window

Comment: Can Anyone Pelase help me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This been done using Set method from Java then clicking on parent window then passing on the control to child and then again passing on the control to second child window and likewise series we can follow.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you to switch to child window :

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
   for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
     // Switch to child window
     driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
   }
```

You can also handle multiple child window , [Check here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/) for that.

Comment: Is that Javascript popup? or another child window?

Comment: Can you share website URL? So I can see something real to help you.

Comment: Ok , I have added one link to answer , that will help you to achieve your need.

Comment: I got your issue. You want to handle nested child window.

Comment: As I told , please check page which I shared in link of my answer. That will help you to handle nested window.

Comment: Yes I have checked i am writing the code but it is not performing operations on the second child window

Answer (score 0):

Guys now I am able to Handle the third child window and perform operation on it.
The problem was with that i was not able to identify the third child window element.